# Align icon at text left in a Button

Tags: java, android, button, icons

How I can align the icon at text left? If I put `drawableStart` it appears at the center-top of the button.

[image]

Comment: please add your code template.

Comment: I only want to center the icon

Comment: @David you want icon at center or left ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `center_vertical` will align your text to center and if your drawable has invisible padding please check. Also, check if the background resource has any padding. Otherwise below code will work fine.

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp" 
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_info"
    android:text="@string/app_name"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp" // padding in between icon and text
    android:paddingStart="40dp" // start padding for icon
    />
```